# Using jQuery to select a dynamically created element

Tags: jquery, html, getjson

Trying to figure this one out and I think I know the problem but I don't know how to fix it. When my page first loads I'm using a JSON file to provide some links on the page, using $.getJSON to create them and give them ID's, dynamically. My code for that is (this is just the bit I'm interested in for now, I of course close the function):

```
    $(function() {

        $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
            var navOutput = "";
            for (var key in data.navigation) {
                navOutput += '<li><a id="' + key + '">' + data.navigation[key] + '</a></li>'; // Create list items with ID 'key'
            }
            $("#mainNav").html(navOutput);
```

Everything loads fine on the page. Outside of the $.getJSON function I am trying to assign an event listener to one of those dynamically created ID's, as an example:

```
$("#cast").click(function() {
    alert("Testing");
}); //click function
```

This doesn't seem to work. There is probably a simple answer to this but I can't figure it out. If I assign an event handler to an ID on the page created in the HTML, it works, so it has something to do with these dynamic ID's. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When do you do these things relative to each other? Adding the click callback will only apply to the elements which exist *at that point*, so you will need to add the callback after the JSON has been included.

Comment: Hi Dave, I'm adding the event handler after getJSON (further down the page, outside of the function). It's initially why I thought the id's would have been created by the time it got to the event handler.

Comment: There's no guarantee that just because it's further down it will happen after the JSON has loaded; network latency means it probably won't have. You need to only add the hook from within the function you pass to `getJSON` (or some function it calls). Or use phobos' solution, which will work on all future elements as well as existing (but adds slight overhead).

Comment: Ah! Okay, thanks Dave. Gotcha. Phobos' solution worked for me. Good call on the latency, I never thought about that. Cheers =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
$("#cast").click(function() {
    alert("Testing");
});
```

to

```
$("body").on("click","#cast",function(e) {
    alert("Testing");
});
```

You need to set handler with `on` instead of `click`. It's advancement to `live()`. It'll allow you to attach handler to dynamically loaded elements. `click` will attach only on dom ready ie while page is laoded initially.

Comment: For some reason doing that replacement seems to prevent my JSON file from loading at all. I'll have a closer look at "on" and "live". Thanks =)

Comment: you don't need to put this inside `$.getJSON` callback. Just put it anywhere in do ready. Did you see any error after updating code as above ?

Comment: Nope, no more errors. The event handler is outside of the getJSON callback, but still inside the document.ready. Works great. Thanks a ton Phobos and Dave! =)

Comment: One last thing, is "on" a replacement for "live" (ie. is "live" deprecated?)

Comment: @user1886786 yes.. it was deprecated in since 1.7 and removed in 1.9 as per docs.

Comment: That reminds me, I should change my user ID, it's not very flattering. And cool, thanks!